# Getting a List from another class

Tags: java, list, class

I've been trying to figure out how to make a List from classA accessible for ClassB
I've tried creating an instance/object of the list but it always returns empty when I get the size of the list (while in the main class its not empty).

**Example:**

ClassA:

```
List<String> players = new ArrayList<String>();
```

If i used `players.size()` here it would return 2 for example

in ClassB I tried the following:

```
 ClassA classA = new ClassA();
 List<String> newList = classA.players;
```

`newList.size()` will always return 0 no matter what.

I've also tried using a getter but that doesn't seem to make a difference.

**Example:**

ClassA:

```
List<String> players = new ArrayList<String>();
public List<String> getList(){
    return this.players;
}
```

ClassB:

```
ClassA.getList().size()
```

This will also always return 0

How would I properly do this? I tried using a static and that seemed to work but i've been told:

> "Static is not the right tool for the job. It's a memory management
>   tool, not an access modifier."

He told me:

> Instead of static and instead of creating new instances, you can pass
>   instances to other classes by adding them as parameters to the
>   constructor

However I don't really get what he means. If someone could explain this with an example that would be amazing. Thanks in advance!

**Edit:** Since a lot of you don't quite get where i want to go with this i'll post my source:
**refered to as ClassA in the example**

```
public class TeamManager {

String prefix = new Messages().prefix;
List<String> players = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> human = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> infected = new ArrayList<String>();

void join(Player p){
    if(!players.contains(p.getName())){
        players.add(p.getName());
        teleportToLobby(p);
        for (String temp : players) {
            Bukkit.getPlayer(temp).sendMessage("§e§l"+p.getName()+ " has joined infection. §7("+players.size()+"/16)");
        }
    }else{
        p.sendMessage(prefix + "§cFailed. You are already in the game!");
    }
}
void leave(Player p){
    if(players.contains(p.getName())){
        p.teleport(Bukkit.getWorlds().get(0).getSpawnLocation());
        players.remove(p.getName());
        for (String temp : players) {
            Bukkit.getPlayer(temp).sendMessage("§7§l"+p.getName()+ " has left infection. §7("+players.size()+"/16)");
        }
    }else{
        p.sendMessage(prefix + "§cYou are not in a game!");
    }
}
void addToHumans(String playername){
    human.add(playername);
}
void removeFromHumans(String playername){
    human.remove(playername);
}
void addToInfected(String playername){
    infected.add(playername);
}
void removeFromInfected(String playername){
    infected.remove(playername);
}

void teleportToLobby(Player p){
    Location lobby = getLocFromConfig("lobby");
    if(lobby != null){
        p.teleport(lobby);
        p.sendMessage(prefix + "§aSuccessfully added to game!");
    }else{
        p.sendMessage(prefix + "§cLobby not set! Make sure to set a lobby using /infection setlobby");
    }
}
void startGame(){
    /*if(human.size() >= 4){
    }*/
    for (String temp : players) {
        Bukkit.getPlayer(temp).sendMessage("Game will start shortly!");
    }
}
Location getLocFromConfig(String locationName){
    if(Main.plugin.getConfig().get("lobby") != null){
        double x = Main.plugin.getConfig().getInt(locationName+".x");
        double y = Main.plugin.getConfig().getInt(locationName+".y");
        double z = Main.plugin.getConfig().getInt(locationName+".z");
        World world = Main.plugin.getServer().getWorld(Main.plugin.getConfig().getString(locationName+".world"));
        Location l = new Location(world, x, y, z);
        return l;
    }else{
        Bukkit.getLogger().warning("[Infection] Lobby has not been set!");
        return null;
    }
}
int getPlayersInLobby(){
    return players.size();
}

public List<String> getPlayers(){
    List<String> players = this.players;
    return players;
}
public List<String> getHumans(){
    return human;
}
public List<String> getInfected(){
    return infected;
}
```

}

**Events class (referred to in the example as ClassB)**

```
public class Events implements Listener{

TeamManager teamman = new TeamManager();
List<String> players = teamman.getPlayers();
List<String> humans = teamman.getHumans();
List<String> infected = teamman.getInfected();
@EventHandler
public void onPlayerJoin(PlayerJoinEvent e){
    //Player p = (Player) e.getPlayer();
    //e.setJoinMessage("["+lvl+"]" + e.getPlayer().getName() +"has joined the game!");
    //p.setDisplayName("[lvl1]"+p.getName());

}
@EventHandler
public void onPlayerDamage(EntityDamageByEntityEvent  e){
    if(e.getEntity() instanceof Player){
        Player p = (Player) e.getEntity();
        Bukkit.getServer().broadcastMessage("Players: "+ players);
        if(players.contains(p.getName())){
            if((p.getHealth() - p.getLastDamage()) < 1){
                for (String temp : players) {
                    Bukkit.getPlayer(temp).sendMessage("§c"+p.getName()+" got infected by "+p.getKiller().getName()+"!");
                }
                e.setCancelled(true);
                 p.setHealth(20);
                 teamman.addToInfected(p.getName());
                 teamman.removeFromHumans(p.getName());
                 p.sendMessage("§cYou have been infected!!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

As said above i want to be able to access the lists from TeamManager and use them in Events. And as explained `players` is empty in the Events class. I hope this helps.

Comment: You don't have any players in your list. You could add players in your constructor, create players when you create the list, or create a method that lets you add players to the list.

Comment: @ThomasK I know how to add to the list, I just left it out for simplicity.

Comment: How can you call `ClassA.getList().size()` if `getList()` is not static ? And once you make `getList` static you have to make `players` static. But make it static only if you want an instance-independent list. But the fact that you need instance-independent list tells me that your design could be improved.

Comment: @svasa if i use static lists it works. But i've been recommended not to use it. So thats why i'm asking for a different method.

Comment: @DarkEyeDragon a different method is to pass the class A itself or the list to class B's constructor as suggested in answers below.

Answer (score 0):

Every time you do

```
ClassA classA = new ClassA();
List<String> newList = classA.players;
```

will create/have new instance of ArrayList declared in ClassA.

And, since below line of code is an instance variable. So, each instance will have different copy.

```
List<String> players = new ArrayList<String>();
```

So, solution are :

```
 ClassA classA = new ClassA();
 classA.players.add("A");
 List<String> newList = classA.players;
```

Or have setter method or initialize in constructor or declared it as static member. This all solution will depends on your requirement.

> Instead of static and instead of creating new instances, you can pass
>   instances to other classes by adding them as parameters to the
>   constructor

This means you could pass ClassA instance to ClassB using constructor.

Comment: @Jason I didn't get you ? So, you are saying you didn't get the answer explained ?

Comment: @Ravi Wouldn't that give the same result tho? Instead of viewing/editing the existing List i would just be adding it to the new instance no?

Comment: No, what i meant was, my answer is very close to yours, but yours is better

Comment: @DarkEyeDragon As I mentioned in my answer. everything depends on your requirement. But, I'm assuming you are going to have only one instance of ClassA.

Comment: @DarkEyeDragon I have shared multiple solution. You could try any.

Comment: Class `B` can have `A a = new A();`. It can have `public void doSomething(A a)...`. It can have `public B(A a)...`. Conversely, `A` could have `B b = new B();`, `public void doSomeStuff(B b)...`. It can have `public A(B b)...`. `B` can pass the list to an `A` instance by `a.foo(players)`, or `A` can get it via `List<String> players = b.getPlayers();`. Etc.

Answer (score 0):

i think your problem is that you are not thinking about the objects independently. Only when you initialize the instance of class A inside class B can that instance be mutated.

You can then pass the object around from class B to where ever you would like, but you cant initialize class A from class a then directly use it in class B unless you pass it to class B

Comment: I really don't understand this answer at all. On the face, it's wrong. You can mutate an instance of `A` without having it initialized from `B`, so that "[o]nly when you..." part is wrong. What do you mean by "pass the object around from class B to where ever _[sic]_ you would like"? And you certainly can create an object of type `A` from inside `B` without any "passing" going on. And you "initialize class A" by referring to any static member of `A` or instantiating it, among other techniques. Please clarify and correct your answer.

Comment: i will edit it, but you're misreading it. i didn't say you had to pass it anywhere, i said once initialized it COULD be passed... "Initialize the instance of class A inside of class B"

Answer (score 0):

The list of A will always be empty, because you are access a list of a new instance. If you want get a list A, you have send a list A as parameter to class B. Example:

```
class ClassA{
 List<String> players; 
 ClassA(){
  players = new ArrayList<>();
 }
 public List getPlayers(){
  return this.players;
 }
}

class ClassB{
  private List<String> playersA;

  ClassB(List playersA){
   this.playersA = playersA;
 }
}

// In your main code

ClassA classA = new ClassA();
ClassB classB;
List<String> players = classA.getPlayers();
players.add("P1");
players.add("P2");

classB = new ClassB(players);
```

Comment: You don't have to "send a list A as parameter to class B", you could get it from within class `B` using a getter method in the class `A` instance. `List<String> players = instanceA.getPlayers();`. This has its own problems in that the `B` code now has the ability to change the list held in the `A` instance. For this you might need a defensive (deep) copy.

Comment: Maybe, but not is the situation. Also, it is not specified whether class B has a reference to an instance of A or create an instance A within herself.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is that you need the same instance of ClassA that you created to be passed into ClassB.

When you create a class, you are created the class definition. Each time you use the `new` keyword, you create a new instance of that class. You can have as many instances of a class as you want, assuming you've got enough memory. But each instance is separate from all the others.

Just like String and List are classes and need to be instantiated, your custom classes do as well. So in your main, or wherever you're using ClassA and ClassB, you'll want to instantiate them like:

```
ClassA instanceOfClassA = new ClassA();
ClassB instanceOfClassB = new ClassB();
```

Let's assume, since you didn't specify, that you did that in your main.

**You're objective:** Access the list of a specific instance of ClassA from within ClassB.

You've already created the getList() method in ClassA. That's good. You'll use that.

Next, you'll want to create a data member inside ClassB that is of type ClassA, as well as a getter and setter for that member:

```
public class ClassB {
    ...
    ClassA myInstanceOfClassA;

    public void setClassAInstance(ClassA instance){
        this.myInstanceOfClassA = instance;
    }
    public ClassA getClassAInstance(){
        return this.myInstanceOfClassA;
    }
}
```

Then, back in your main, after you've updated the `players` in that instance of ClassA, and after you've instantiated your instance of ClassB like above:

```
instanceOfClassB.setClassAInstance(instanceofClassA);
```

Then inside ClassB, the list of `players` is accessible using that instance.

```
List<String> playersFromClassA = myInstanceOfClassA.getList();
```

Likewise, calling `myInstanceOfClassA.getList().size();` from inside ClassB should return the appropriate number of players.

Comment: I've edited my post a bit. I hope this makes more sense.